# How to send data to base template without controller?

Tags: symfony, controller, twig

I need to get the data from entity in the base template (twig), but not rendering this data from controller.

Specifically, I want to realize the menu. Menu labels stored in the database (Page entity). I have many controllers and I don't want to repeat the code of the entity handling in each controller.

I could extend the controller's classes, but I want to avoid stuff like this:

```
    return $this->render('... .html.twig', 
                          array(
                          ...
                          'menu' => $labels,
                          ...
                           )
                        );
```

in each of the controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the perfect use-case for an [embedded controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers). You can call a new controller from your template for rendering a part of your response, in this case the menu. It can have any logic a controller can, meaning you can query your database, build your menu structure and render a twig file for outputting it as html.

Comment: fresh documantation url http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html